# Reverse String (Leetcode) Using C++, Why I cannot return the new string as method

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Question:  Write a function that takes a string as input and returns the string reversed.

Example:  Given s = "hello", return "olleh".

What's wrong with this code?

```
class Solution {
public:
    string reverseString(string s) {

        string s2;

        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
            s2[i] = s[s.length()-1-i];

        return s2;
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot do this way"?  What indication(s) do you have that this is wrong?

Comment: yes, that is reversed copy, what's wrong in this code?

Comment: Oh, I practice the question on this website #344
https://leetcode.com/problemset/algorithms/

Comment: But my answer is not the correct answer....

Comment: You should test your own code. And try not to write outside the bounds of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got out of bound access, you have to resize result string before assign it.

```
std::string reverseString(const std::string& s) {
    std::string s2(s.size(), '\0');

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        s2[i] = s[s.length()-1-i];

    return s2;
}
```

Or simply use correct constructor:

```
std::string reverseString(const std::string& s) {
    return {s.rbegin(), s.rend()};
}
```

Comment: That should be `(s.size(), '\0')` (or some other character, or a call to `resize`). `std::string` opted for no constructor taking only a size because `std::string s = 'a';` would not initialize it to 1 character (a).

Answer (score 2):

Because the very first iteration of the loop attempts to set `s2[0]` to the last character of the original string.

The problem is that there is no `s2[0]`. The `s2` string is completely empty. The `s2` string is, essentially, an empty array.

Attempting to access the contents of the string using the `[]` operator accesses the ***existing*** character of that string. It doesn't create one, if it doesn't exist.

Even if code execution survives this undefined behavior, on the next iteration of the loop an attempt gets made to set `s2[1]` to some character. `s2[1]` does not exist, any more than `s2[0]` did. And so on. Undefined behavior. Crash.

Instead of setting non-existent values of an empty string, just use `push_back()` to add each character to `s2`.

This isn't really a particuarly efficient approach to reversing the contents of the string, of course. But it's a fine first attempt at tackling this introductory task.

Comment: Sam, thank you so much for my limited experience with string & array concept ...... I got it

Comment: Thanks ... @Sam Varshavchik